# Taking derivative takes forever and the output with `Root` and pound sign

Tags: equation-solving, differentials

I'm taking derivative under assumptions on parameters and it is taking forever. Here is my code:

```
Assuming[0 < r < 1/2 && 0 < s && 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 2 d < s &&r s > d, 
FullSimplify@Reduce[D[-((c (1 - 2 r + 2 q r) (d^4 - 2 d^2 r s^2 + 2 d^2 r^2 s^2))/(4 (-1 + r)^2 r^2 s^4)), r] == 0, r]]
```

I've been running it for last 24 hours and it is still running.

[Edit]: So, following cvgmt's comment to this post, I used `Simplify` as follows:

```
Simplify[Reduce[D[-((c (1 - 2 r + 2 q r) (d^4 - 2 d^2 r s^2 + 2 d^2 r^2 s^2))/(4 (-1 + r)^2 r^2 s^4)), r] == 0, r], 0 < r < 1/2 && 0 < s && 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 2 d < s &&r s > d]
```

And the output looks weird as follows:

[image]

How do you interpret this result?

Comment: Use `Simplify`.

Comment: @cvgmt, thanks! Following your comment, I got some result which includes `Root` and pound sign, which I included in the edit of the post. Can you please help on how to interpret it?

Comment: Read the documentation for `Root`

Comment: For the `#1`, read about [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html)


`Root[f,k]` gives the k-th root of the polynomial f. So for example `Root[#1^2 - #1 - 1 &, 2]` gives the golden ratio.

If you want a radical expression expression instead of a `Root`, you can call `ToRadicals` on you root objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem effectively boils down to finding the roots of a polynomial, and for polynomials of order 4, Mathematica will not usually display them in terms of radicals (and for polynomials of order 5 or higher, no general solution in terms of radicals exists).

Instead, it uses [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects, where `Root[{poly, i}]` gives you the $i$th root of $poly$.

However, $poly$ will be represented as a **pure function**, where the `#` character represents a "slot" which is filled in when the function is applied, and `&` tells Mathematica where the function ends. We can see this like so:

```
f = a*#^2 + b*# + c &;
f[x]
(* c + b x + a x^2 *)
```

If you plug this familiar polynomial into `Root`, Mathematica will evaluate it to radicals immediately:

```
Root[f, 1]
(* -(b/(2 a)) - 1/2 Sqrt[(b^2 - 4 a c)/a^2] *)
```

For a fourth order polynomial like the one you found, you need [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) to get it expanded out. Trying it here is a good way to see why Mathematica doesn't do it that way by default:

```
ToRadicals[Root[-d^2 + (3 d^2 - d^2 q + s^2) #1 + (-3 d^2 + 3 d^2 q - 
      3 s^2) #1^2 + (4 s^2 - 2 q s^2) #1^3 + (-2 s^2 + 
      2 q s^2) #1^4 &, 1]]
(* an expression that is several pages long *)
```